# Visualization of 3D streamlines in ParaView

Tags: visualization, paraview

[image: The kind of flow plot I'm trying to get]

Essentially I want to use paraview to recreate a flow visualization like the one shown in the picture above. I am able to create the 3d flow lines using a pipeline that looks like

```
data (csv)-> TableToStructuredGrid -> Calculator-> ExtractSubset -> StreamTracerwithCustomSource
```

where I have used the subset as my seed. However I have no idea how to project the 3d flow onto the walls as shown in the picture. There is an option in streamlines called "surface streamlines" but this restricts streamlines to live in a plane whereas I want to project my 3d streamlines down into a plane and display them on the back 3 faces of the bounding cube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackOverflow has a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544709/paraview-view-a-2d-projection-of-a-3d-object) to yours. Although, it is not exactly the same.

The following is a pipeline for what you want:

```
StreamTracer1
 |— Transform1
 |— Transform2
 |— Transform3
```

Where each transformation correspond to a projection and a translation, namely:

$$P_x = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 &0 &\Delta x\\
0 &1 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &1\\\end{pmatrix}\, ,\quad
P_y = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &\Delta y\\
0 &0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &1\\\end{pmatrix}\, ,\quad
P_z = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0 &\Delta z\\
0 &0 &0 &1\\\end{pmatrix}\, ,$$

where I used homogeneous coordinates, and $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$, $\Delta z$ are the location of the planes where you want your projection to be placed.

In ParaView, the transformation correspond to the field in `Transform > Translate` and `Tranform > Scale`, as shown below

[image]

Using this approach I get the following result

[image]

That is close to what you want.